# Scala: Memory issues

Tags: scala, memory-management, playframework, jvm

I'm faced with an optimisation challenge. 
I'm in the middle of writing a Scala based service that uses Play Framework and ElasticSearch to analyse about 200k documents in an index.

Now, the analysis can only be done on all the documents at once, and I have a model class on top of ES, which when passed as a list to another method, draws the analysis on the model class.

Now, to fetch the 200k documents at once and analyse them is out of the question since that is beyond our constraints. So what I did was this –
From within a recursive function:

```
def getOverallAnalytics(accumulatedAnalytics: Map[...], limit: Int, startFrom: Int) = {
    ElasticModel.getAnalytics(limit, startFrom).flatMap({
        case (hasMore, newAnalytics) => {
            val combinedAnalytics = combine(accumulatedAnalytics, newAnalytics)
            if (hasMore) getOverallAnalytics(combinedAnalytics, limit, startFrom + limit)
            else Future(newAccumulator)
        }
    })        
}
```

And you have;

```
object ElasticModel {
    getAnalytics(limit, startFrom) = {
        val recordObjects = queryElastic.flatMap(result => new ElasticModel(result))
        Future((haveMore(), getAnalysis(recordObjects))) //
    }
}
```

Something to that effect. Now, the map containing the analytics has a very small set of keys. Given this, one would not expect to see a

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
Unable to create new native thread
```

Which is running on a 16GB RAM machine.

My assumptions: `recordObjects` doesn't keep consuming memory once the call to `getAnalytics` finishes.

That seems like the only possibility where this is going wrong.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you are having less a traditional OOM error and more of an issue with resources on your machine.  Is your threadpool bounded and if so, what is the max size?  Also, do you have your machine setup to have a large number of available file descriptors as this error can come from that too.  Are you properly closing your http connections to ES so that they are not leaked?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to avoid that captured reference to `recordObjects`:

```
object ElasticModel {
    def getAnalytics(limit, startFrom): Future[(Boolean, 'Analytics')] = {
        Future((
          haveMore(), 
          getAnalysis(queryElastic.flatMap(result => new ElasticModel(result)))
        ))
    }
}
```

However, could you not pull a memory dump and check, if `recordObjects` heap up?

Comment: `recordObjects` is limited per call to getAnalytics to about 500, which isn't a particularly large number.

Comment: One `recordObjects` may not be a problem, but if (somehow) capturing it in a `val` that is referenced from a *Future closure* within a recursive function results in the vm not garbage collecting the `recordObjects`, they may heap up to more than vm heap can manage. I am not sure this is the culprit. My other suspect would be the recursion. Therefore, I'd suggest to look at a memory dump and check whether or not the reason for the *OOME* is accumulated `recordObjects`. The suggested code in my answer is more of a diagnostic test ;)